# Scroll if div is hidden by overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, scroll

I'm looking detect when a div with class '.selected' is below the bottom of its container div (hidden by overflow:hidden). If it is, scroll down the contents of the container to reveal the next 'page', either by scrolling the equivalent of the container's height or by scrolling until the '.selected' is at the top of it's container again.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Try looking up scrollTo on jquery site.  I used a similar thing for the Theakstons website online shop

Comment: @aaron I haven't tried anything yet, I thought I'd ask on here before I jumped into it. I've found this though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287425/overflow-hidden-jquery-selector which is kind of related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `scrollTo` and some of the math from the link I posted in the comment to make this:

```
var top = it.position().top; 
var bd = top + it.height();     
var ch = $('.tab-demo-content').height();     
if(bd>ch){  //if focused item isn't visible, scroll to it
    $(it).closest('.tv-container-vertical').scrollTo(it,500);   //this finds its parent container and scrolls it
}
```

- `bd` =distance from top of container to selected item's bottom
- `ch` = content container height

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate native (non-jquery) javascript code is:

```
element.scrollIntoView(); // Equivalent to element.scrollIntoView(true)
element.scrollIntoView(alignToTop); // Boolean arguments
element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions); // Object argument
```

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView )

most modern browsers support scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() too:

```
element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
```